# Problems understanding how to parse/pass sequelize find results

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out how to get to a particular attribute in a sequelize search query. I've tried to use the attributes option but that doesn't seem to work in the way I expect...

```
async function getImagesByPetName(petname) {
  const images = await Images.findAll({
    attributes: ['Location'],
    where: {
      Petname: petname.toLowerCase(),
    },
 });
     return images;
    //return JSON.stringify(images,
}
```

It does filter correctly and I get these results:

```
Images are : [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "Petname": "archie",
    "Name": "hulk-onyx-archie.jpg",
    "Location": "https://snootly.s3.amazonaws.com/hulk-onyx-archie.jpg",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-28T12:04:24.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-28T12:04:24.000Z",
    "PetId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "Petname": "archie",
    "Name": "archie-older.jpg",
    "Location": "https://snootly.s3.amazonaws.com/archie-older.jpg",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-28T12:04:25.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-28T12:04:25.000Z",
    "PetId": null
  }
]
```

My main issue is how to access the location of each image array...

```
app.get("/getimages", (req, res) => {
  var id = req.query.id;
  db.getImagesByPetName(id).then((images) => {
    //loop through the image record and pull out the url
   //var imagelist = [];
  // for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      console.log("The location is: " + images[12]);
   //       imagelist.push(images[i].Location);
    //}
    console.log("Images are : " + images);

    res.send(images);
  });
});
```

This is how I set up the database models:

```
onst Pets = sequelize.define(
  "Pets",
  {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
    image: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    
  },
  {}
);

const Images = sequelize.define(
  "Images",
  {
    Petname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    Name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
    Location: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  {}
);

Images.belongsTo(Pets);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine. The attribute keyword is now working and returning just the one field. It seemed to be an issue with git.